# Get Date value from Grails DatePicker

Tags: forms, grails, datepicker

How to get date values in month, year and days in grails datePicker

```
<g:datePicker id="test" name="test" precision="day"></g:datePicker >
```

I tried using `getDate()` but I do not get any value.

Comment: Where are you trying to access it?

Comment: I am trying to print out the date on my gsp page like Sept 4, 2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this approach, first register `change` handler to each of the 3 selects generated by the datePicker tag, then call the `dateWasChanged` method and inside that build your date and update your `mydate` div.

> Note: On date Object month is 0 base (index) so you need to deduct 1 unit from the actual select value.

```
    <body>
        <g:datePicker  id="test" name="test" precision="day"></g:datePicker >
        <div id="mydate"></div>

        <script  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        dateWasChanged()

        $( "#test_day" ).change(function() {
            dateWasChanged();
        });     
        $( "#test_month" ).change(function() {
            dateWasChanged();
        }); 
        $( "#test_year" ).change(function() {
            dateWasChanged();
        }); 

        function dateWasChanged(){
            var year = $( "#test_year" ).val();
            var month = $( "#test_month" ).val()-1;
            var day = $( "#test_day" ).val();
            var date = new Date(year,month,day);
             $("#mydate").text(date.toString())
        }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But I do not have seperate select field for year, momth and day. I have a calendar picker, and a text field that shows date as 09/05/2013.

Comment: What you are showing is Grails default `<g:datePicker>` tag, which will generate 3 selects for you. I might be mistaken But the idea is find your date div or whatever element it has with id or however you can refer to it, read its value and update your destination div.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like the following:

```
Date myDate = params.date('test', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

That will give you a good ol' fashioned `java.util.Date` object with Groovy extensions that you can use from there. Be sure to set the format (in my case `'dd-MM-yyyy'`) to whatever date format you are using.

Comment: But how do I access it using $('#test').click or $('#test').datePicker

Comment: Wait, you want to access it client-side? Please update your question and add more information. What exactly do you want to happen? What have you tried? Client- or server-side? Are you wanting to get date values in a controller? GSP? Do you want it to display `onchange`? All the information you are adding in comments should have been in the question from the start.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have a datepicker field on my form. Without submitting the form , just by selecting the date I want to print it out on the form (gsp file) what I selected. How this can be done using grails?

Comment: Ah, yes, that changes things. I don't know a ton about JavaScript, unfortunately. I would look at @Alidad's answer. It looks correct.