# Grails make one g:datePicker depend on other g:datePicker

Tags: grails, datepicker

imagine that you have an index.gsp with two dates: Starting day and Ending Day.

When the user picks the starting day, how can I calculate + 2 months in the ending day?

I know in the controller I could have something like:

```
use (TimeCategory) {
    c = new Date() + 2.month
}
```

But how is the best way to change the Ending Day in the gsp? With remoteFunction?

EDIT:
Yes it worked, thank you very much lukelazarovic.

Like you said the only thing needed to change was the last line, I changed to: $("#myid_month").val(month+3);

```
    function dateWasChanged(){
    ....
         $("#myid_month").val(month+3);
    }
```

EDIT2:
I also needed to increment year, for some reason they are strings so remember to do:
myInteger = parseInt(myString);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to do it on the client - without reloading page +2 months date is set into the end date datePicker.

That means you have to do it using Javascript or Javascript-based framework (JQuery).

You can go along with the solution suggested in this SO question: [Get Date value from Grails DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625550/get-date-value-from-grails-datepicker)
Only change would be to set the value of end datePicker on the last line of function dateWasChanged like this:

```
$("#endDatePickerId").datpicker("setDate", date);
```

Comment: Yes and yes, ok but can JQuery make operations with dates like adding 2 months? or is it better to do it in a grails controller?

Comment: JQuery is capable to do it for sure - I have updated my answer. From user's perspective it's much better to do it on the client than to reload whole page..

Comment: Ok I'll try that, thank you very much.
By the way, I wasn't thinking in reloading the whole page, I think is possible with the remoteFunction

Comment: I see, that could be also the way but more complicated than necessary IMHO